# ffmpeg stream decoding - artefacts when not using ffplay

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, h.264

I stream a video capture via RTP using libx264. For now, I just stream to localhost.
For watching the stream, I use the ffmpeg library. When I set the GOP size greater than 1 (only I frames), I get artefacts on the receiver side [image: received image]. The strange thing is, when I use ffplay, the image is perfect [image: like original]. What am I doing wrong?

Settings for encoding

```
output_codec_ctx->bit_rate = 5000000;
output_codec_ctx->width = 1920;
output_codec_ctx->height = 1080;
output_codec_ctx->time_base.den = 30; // frames per second
output_codec_ctx->time_base.num = 1;
output_codec_ctx->gop_size = 10; // gop size
output_codec_ctx->max_b_frames = 0; // B frames
output_codec_ctx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P; // output pixel format
output_codec_ctx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;

av_opt_set(output_codec_ctx->priv_data, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
av_opt_set(output_codec_ctx->priv_data, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);
```

Code for decoding

```
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;
AVCodecContext *input_codec_ctx;
AVCode *pCodec;
avdevice_register_all(); // for device
avformat_network_init();
pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
input_codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(nullptr);
AVDictionary *options = nullptr;
av_dict_set(&options, "protocol_whitelist", "file,udp,rtp", 0);
av_dict_set(&options, "fflags", "nobuffer",0);

avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, "rtp://127.0.0.1:49990", nullptr, &options);

avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, nullptr);
for (uint i = 0; i < pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
 {
   if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
   {
     videoStream = static_cast<int>(i);
     break;
   }

 }

av_read_play(pFormatCtx);    //play stream
pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codecpar->codec_id);
AVCodecParameters *codec_param = pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codecpar;
avcodec_parameters_to_context(input_codec_ctx, codec_param);
avcodec_open2(input_codec_ctx, pCodec, nullptr);

AVPacket packet;
AVPacket *pkt  = &packet;
AVFrame *frame;
frame = av_frame_alloc();

av_init_packet(pkt);
pkt->data = nullptr;    // packet data will be allocated by the encoder
pkt->size = 0;

while(true){
    av_read_frame(pFormatCtx,pkt);
    avcodec_send_packet(input_codec_ctx,pkt);
    avcodec_receive_frame(input_codec_ctx,frame);
}
```

Initialization and stuff omitted. Console output for custom decoding:

```
NULL @ 0x1fb7b80] Opening 'stream.sdp' for reading
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] Format sdp probed with size=2048 and score=50
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] video codec set to: h264
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] RTP Packetization Mode: 1
[udp @ 0x1f34140] end receive buffer size reported is 131072
[udp @ 0x1fb8e40] end receive buffer size reported is 131072
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] setting jitter buffer size to 500

 Success !
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 181 bytes read:181 seeks:0 nb_streams:1
[AVBSFContext @ 0x1fa5880] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[AVBSFContext @ 0x1fa5880] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[AVBSFContext @ 0x1fa5880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[AVBSFContext @ 0x1fa5880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[AVBSFContext @ 0x1fa5880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[AVBSFContext @ 0x1fa5880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[AVBSFContext @ 0x1fa5880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[AVBSFContext @ 0x1fa5880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[AVBSFContext @ 0x1fa5880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[AVBSFContext @ 0x1fa5880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] Format yuv420p chosen by get_format().
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] Reinit context to 1920x1088, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] RTP: missed 57 packets
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] Invalid level prefix
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] error while decoding MB 2 36
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] concealing 3887 DC, 3887 AC, 3887 MV errors in I frame
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] RTP: missed 155 packets
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] corrupted macroblock 32 41 (total_coeff=-1)
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] error while decoding MB 32 41
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] concealing 3257 DC, 3257 AC, 3257 MV errors in I frame
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1fa51c0] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] RTP: missed 52 packets
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] RTP: missed 51 packets
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] RTP: missed 10 packets
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] RTP: missed 50 packets
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] RTP: missed 52 packets
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] All info found
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 181 bytes read:181 seeks:0 frames:28
found video stream 

The number of elements in stream is  1 

[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] Format yuv420p chosen by get_format().
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] Reinit context to 1920x1088, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] RTP: missed 256 packets
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] Invalid level prefix
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] error while decoding MB 119 41
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] concealing 3170 DC, 3170 AC, 3170 MV errors in I frame
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] RTP: missed 5 packets
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] RTP: missed 4 packets
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] out of range intra chroma pred mode
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] error while decoding MB 100 56
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] corrupted macroblock 84 65 (total_coeff=-1)
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] error while decoding MB 84 65
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] concealing 754 DC, 754 AC, 754 MV errors in I frame
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] RTP: missed 160 packets
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] corrupted macroblock 17 36 (total_coeff=-1)
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] error while decoding MB 17 36
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] concealing 3872 DC, 3872 AC, 3872 MV errors in I frame
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[sdp @ 0x1fb7b80] RTP: missed 53 packets
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] corrupted macroblock 62 39 (total_coeff=-1)
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] error while decoding MB 62 39
[h264 @ 0x1ee3880] concealing 3467 DC, 3467 AC, 3467 MV errors in I frame
```

Comment: Try with GOP = 14 and, likely, max_b_frames = 2

Comment: @Ripi2 doesn't change anything

Comment: Might be related to https://superuser.com/questions/1349925/artifact-while-streaming-multicast-with-ffmpeg?newreg=b9c43a92c5f94a008e14b1235e65e1f3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end I solved it by implementing it the same way ffplay does: One thread performs av_read_frame() and pushes the received packets to a packetqueue, and a second thread decodes the packets.

No idea why it does not work in one thread.

You might get an example from the following snippets:

PacketReceiver:

```
must_abort = false; // class member, externally set to true if abort requested
AVPacket packet;
AVPacket *pkt  = &packet;
int ret;

while (must_abort == false){
    ret = av_read_frame(pFormatCtx,pkt);
    if (ret>=0 && !must_abort){
        queue->putPacket(pkt);
    }
    else{
        qDebug("no packet received");
    }
    QApplication::processEvents();
}
```

PacketQueue:

```
class PacketQueue{
public:
void init(){
    abort_request = false;
}
void putPacket(AVPacket *pkt) {

    mutex.lock();
    queue.enqueue(*pkt);
    waitForNewPacket.wakeAll();
    mutex.unlock();
}

int getPacket(AVPacket *pkt){
    int ret;
    mutex.lock();
    forever {
        if (abort_request) {
            ret = -1;
            break;
        }
        if (queue.size() == 0){
            if (waitForNewPacket.wait(&mutex, 1000)){
            }else{
                qDebug("PacketQueue timeout, try again...");
            }
            continue;
        }
        *pkt= queue.dequeue();
        ret = 1;
        break;
    }

    mutex.unlock();
    return ret;
}

void abort(){
    mutex.lock();
    abort_request = true;
    mutex.unlock();
}

bool abort_request;
QQueue<AVPacket> queue;
QMutex mutex;
QWaitCondition waitForNewPacket;
};
```

Decoder:

```
AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
AVFrame *frame_RGB = av_frame_alloc();
struct SwsContext *img_convert_ctx = nullptr;
int ret;
int cnt = 0;
int width_current = 0;
int height_current = 0;

avcodec_flush_buffers(mData->input_codec_ctx);

forever{
    cnt++;
    ret = decodeFrame(frame);
    if (ret < 0 ){
        break;
    }
    if (ret == 0){
        continue;
    }

    // check if height and width have changed
    if (width_current != frame->width || height_current != frame->height){
        av_frame_free(&frame_RGB);
        frame_RGB = av_frame_alloc();
        frame_RGB->width = width_current = frame->width;
        frame_RGB->height = height_current = frame->height;
        frame_RGB->format = AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24;
        av_image_alloc(frame_RGB->data, frame_RGB->linesize, frame_RGB->width, frame_RGB->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, 32);
        img_convert_ctx = sws_getContext(   frame->width,
                                            frame->height,
                                            static_cast<AVPixelFormat>(frame->format),
                                            frame->width,
                                            frame->height,
                                            AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
                                            SWS_BICUBIC,
                                            nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    }

    if (img_convert_ctx != nullptr) {
        sws_scale(img_convert_ctx, static_cast<uint8_t const * const  *>(frame->data),
                  frame->linesize, 0, frame->height,
                  frame_RGB->data, frame_RGB->linesize);
        // here is the frame available as RGB in frame_RGB
    }

    av_frame_unref(frame);

}

}

int VideoDecoder::decodeFrame(AVFrame* frame){
int ret = AVERROR(EAGAIN);

forever {
    AVPacket pkt;

    do {
        ret = avcodec_receive_frame(input_codec_ctx, frame);
        if (ret >= 0) {
            //frame->pts = frame->pkt_dts;
            //frame->pts = frame->best_effort_timestamp;
        }

        if (ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
            avcodec_flush_buffers(input_codec_ctx);
            return 0;
        }
        if (ret >= 0)
            return 1;
    } while (ret != AVERROR(EAGAIN));

    if (queue->getPacket(&pkt) < 0)
        return -1;        

    ret = avcodec_send_packet(input_codec_ctx, &pkt);

    if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN)) {
        qFatal("Receive_frame and send_packet both returned EAGAIN, which is an API violation.");
    }

    if (pkt.buf->buffer != nullptr){
        av_packet_unref(&pkt);
    }else{
        qDebug() << "Packet cannot be freed, pkt.buf->buffer == NULL!";
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Just a quick notes on your solution: you are pushing the same AVPacket to queue (as passing same instance by pointer). Rather you should av_packet_alloc each new packet in stream reader and av_packet_free each packet in decoder

Comment: That was on purpose. I wanted to save the time required for allocating and freeing... maybe not best practice, but should be faster, especially for larger bitrates

Comment: I ran into same issue and the multi-threaded approach solved it beautifully. In retrospect, it seems obvious, but doing all this in one thread will potentially block receiving packets on frame decoding. All packet loss disappeared as soon as I separated these processes into multiple threads, and unexpectedly, overall CPU utilization decreased dramatically as well.